# yeoman angular2 webapp generator throws an error on running default serve

Tags: angular, yeoman, yeoman-generator, yeoman-generator-angular

Using yeoman's fountain-webapp generator for an angular2 project.
Ran the generator and on running `npm run serve`, I get the following error,

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because of TypeScript of version 2.4+. Downgrade it to 2.3+. Or, upgrade the rxjs package to 5.4.2. See [Subject::lift has incorrect type signature](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/issues/2539).